# SAPUI5 Routing with context shows no data

Tags: xml, sapui5

I am not able to bind my context to the sap.m.table when routing is used. In SplitApp, when I click on Master page line item, I navigate to detail page and the context using

`contextarg =  decodeURIComponent(evt.getParameter("arguments").ctx);`

Now, I have passed this param to Odata using

```
    var url = "***/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZFIRST_VENDOR_SRV";
    var olineOdataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url,false);
    var rd = contextarg+ "/VENDORITEMSSet";
     olineOdataModel.read(rd,  
              null,  
              null,  
              false,  
              function(oData, oResponse){  

              var oODataJSONModel =  new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();                                        
              oODataJSONModel.setData(oData);  
              // store the model  
              var lineTable = sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview5--lineItemTable");                
              lineTable.setModel(oODataJSONModel,"localModel");
              console.log(lineTable.getModel("localModel"));
```

console shows output as

[image]

and I have done binding with table as

```
<Table id="lineItemTable" headerText="Line Items" items="{'/results'}">
        <columns>
            <Column>
                <header>
                    <Label text="Product ID" />
                </header>
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <header>
                    <Label text="Product Name" />
                </header>
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <header>
                    <Label text="Product Price" />
                </header>
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <header>
                    <Label text="Product Weight (gms)" />
                </header>
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <header>
                    <Label text="Available From" />
                </header>
            </Column>
        </columns>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{ProductId}" />
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{ProductName}" />
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{ProductPrc}" />
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{ProductWt}" />
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{AvailableFrom}" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </Table>
```

But I get No Data on the view. I have tried `items="{'results'}"` and `items="{path:'results'}"`. Kindly help. What mistake I have done here?!

Answer (score 1):

Change your binding to the following:

```
items="{'localModel>/results'}"
```

As you can see the alias for your named model is added. Then also add the alias for the named model you are using to the template:

```
<ColumnListItem>
    <cells>
        <ObjectIdentifier title="{localModel>ProductId}" />
        <ObjectIdentifier title="{localModel>ProductName}" />
        <ObjectIdentifier title="{localModel>ProductPrc}" />
        <ObjectIdentifier title="{localModel>ProductWt}" />
        <ObjectIdentifier title="{localModel>AvailableFrom}" />
    </cells>
</ColumnListItem>
```

Instead of doing all this you could just use

```
lineTable.setModel(oODataJSONModel);
console.log(lineTable.getModel());
```

instead of

```
lineTable.setModel(oODataJSONModel,"localModel");
console.log(lineTable.getModel("localModel"));
```

**Hints:**
You are creating an ODataModel to execute basically an AJAX request. Letting the Component instantiate the ODataModel would be a much better approach in order to make use of the power of OData + the ODataModel in UI5. The [Walkthrough Tutorial](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html) is a good starting point to learn more about that...